# Jenkins Groovy pipeline show failed tests in email that passed on previous test

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am not sure this is possible but here are my current results grab and composed to an email body,

```
@NonCPS
def getTestResults(ip, currentBuild)
{
    def body = """Oh no, something happened to your test for ${ip}"""
    AbstractTestResultAction testResultAction =  currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(AbstractTestResultAction.class)
    def total, failed, skipped, passed = 0
    if (testResultAction != null)
    {
        total = testResultAction.totalCount
        failed = testResultAction.failCount
        skipped = testResultAction.skipCount
        passed = total - failed - skipped
        body = """System ${ip} \n Tests: \n $failed failed | $passed passed | $skipped skipped \n Check console output at: ${env.BUILD_URL}""" ;
    }
    return body
}
```

What I'm hoping to show in the email is if a failure happened on a test that passed on the last run, this can be seen in the Junit chart in Jenkins but so far I have failed to find a way to access this data in my groovy pipeline.
Here is the rest of my code results block,

```
    stage('Results')
    {

        timeout(time: 15, unit: 'MINUTES')
        {
            junit '*.xml'
            def body = getTestResults(ip, currentBuild)
            String emailTo = 'mail' ;
            def subject = "Jenkins"
            def providers = [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'], [$class:'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']]
            emailext to: emailTo, recipientProviders: providers, compressLog: true, subject: subject, body: body
            currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
        }
    }
```

Edit:
I meant to add a picture of what I'm after,
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG1Hj.png)